# Dynamically generate DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm faced with this challenge where I'm creating an editor where I want two object properties to switch place based on a parameter.

```
<div> 
    <pre>{{ member.title.content }}</pre> 
    <pre>{{ member.description.content }}</pre>
</div>
```

The main challenge is to rotate title and description based on the users settings. The controlling variable is also on member, where title and description both have their order-variabel set to either 1 or 2. 
1 and 2 decides order of title and description.

I'm stumped here. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Create an array or Object in Order of their visibility and use ng-repeat to show them accordingly. Remember that object will be generated as per your all criteria and user settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ng-if` as follows,

```
<div ng-if="member.title.order == 1">
    <div> 
      <pre>{{ member.title.content }}</pre> 
      <pre>{{ member.description.content }}</pre>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-else>
     <div> 
        <pre>{{ member.description.content }}</pre>
        <pre>{{ member.title.content }}</pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason I didn't even consider that approach. This simplifies a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question, that you have to change position of title and description depending on your order-variable. For this you need to add "float: left" style whose order-variable is 1.